# Target file "build_runner" not found. - Flutter GraphQL

Tags: flutter

flutter run build_runner build - return the following result

Target file "build_runner" not found.

This is supposed to generate model classes from schema, but stuck in the above listed issues.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the package dependencies. Executing this `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions` will solve this issue.